# O-minimality and forcing

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, forcing, o-minimal

It is well-known that the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1)$ is an o-minimal structure and hence the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is not definable in it.

In an ongoing project with [Will Brian](https://mathoverflow.net/users/70618/will-brian), we are discussing some properties of Cohen and random generic reals. One of the properties we are discussing is about definability of  $\mathbb{Z}$ after adding a Cohen or a random real.

Let $V[G]$ be a generic extension of $V$ by adding a Cohen (resp. random) real $r$
over $V$. Then we can prove the following:

(1) If we consider $r$ as a constant, then  $\mathbb{Z}$  is not definable in 
$(\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1, r)$, and in fact this structure remains o-minimal (this is a known fact).

(2) If we consider $r \subset \mathbb{N}$ as a predicate, then  $\mathbb{Z}$  is  definable in 
$(\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1, r)$ (This is easily seen as $\mathbb{Z}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{V[G]}: \exists a, b \in r, x=a - b  \}$).

We  also have proved the following.

(3) There exists a generic extension $V[G]$ of $V$ by adding a single real $r$,
such that considering $r$ as a predicate, $\mathbb{Z}$  is not  definable in 
$(\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1, r)$.

Now the following question arises.

> **Question**. Let $V[G]$ be a generic extension of $V$ by adding a Cohen (resp. random) real 
>   over $V$. Let $C=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{V[G]}: x$ is Cohen (resp. random) over $V          \}$. Is $\mathbb{Z}$    definable in 
>   $(\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1, C)$.

**Remark.** The structure $(\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1, C)$ is not o-minimal.

Comment: Isn't (1) trivial? Naming an element can't change o-minimality since o-minimality refers to definitions *with* parameters.

Comment: @NoahSchweberN Yes, that is essentially what I had in mind, o-minimality is preserved by adding constants

Comment: (2) seems suspiciously straightforward. In some sense, adding $r\subset {\mathbb N}$ as a predicate you are adding something "very similar" to $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Z$ (but then (3) seems strange - what kind of generic extension gives (3)?) --- Now, for the Question: The set C of all Cohen reals is comeager in the new reals. My quick guess would be that some careful use of genericity implies non-definability of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Does the formula $\phi(x) := \forall y \in C (x+y \in C)$ define the ground reals? (This doesn't have direct bearing on the question, but came up as I was playing around with it)

Comment: @AndrésVillaveces The paper is now available [Combinatorial and number-theoretic properties of generic reals](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.02676).